# Android 3D Flipview involving GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-animation, glsurfaceview

I'm implementing a 3d flip view based on following idea:

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/07/flip-animation-in-android.html

I have two views and one of them is extending from GLSurfaceView and has a custom renderer set on it. The flip works fine if one of the view is based on GLSurfaceView but otherwise when the flip is halfway through as soon as the GLSurfaceView based view is made visible the animation does not work and immediately displays the view instead of smoothly transitioning to it. Any ideas what is causing it ?

Its like half flip takes place and then the half view is rendered without animation.